All Network Interfaces Running By Default?
I have purchased a Mac without doing much more than turning it on. I would like to know if this network overview is normal behavior prior to VPN installation, etc. I have tried via networksetup in command line to list all interfaces and disable ipv6. However, these link local addresses of fe80 remain. They may be important system processes. I suppose I would also need to know the difference if any between the different states for interfaces, such as installed, active, or running. Any tips and insights into this behavior would be much appreciated. (Note that the top interface is awdl0). 
